# When a creature is prone, can it make opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, prone

If a creature is knocked prone, can it still make opportunity attacks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes.**

Neither the rules for being prone (page 277), nor the rules for Opportunity Attacks (page 290) prevent prone combatants from making opportunity attacks.

(both page numbers are for the fourth edition PHB.)

Comment: Don't forget the -2 to the attack roll for being prone.